# Full-screen display on iPad / Display as web app

Tags: ios, wordpress, ipad, themes, mobile-safari

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient approach to tackle an issue. I have wonderful WP themed website that I want to show full-screen on my iPad. Here's how it currently operates:

Once a user has saved the website to their iPad via ‘Add to Home Screen’, the site will launch full-screen (absent any Safari interface) when that icon is pressed. However, a new tab is created with Safari interface items visible once the user clicks on any menu item. I want to keep the full-screen experience (without tabs) while the user remains within the site. I only need this to work when launched from home screen icon in the latest iOS.

1) What is causing the site to launch a new tab? Default mobile safari action due to lack of full-screen code, the way the nav URLs are coded, or other?

2) Is it just a matter of adding some header code to the remaining pages (via child theme or directly to the theme templates)?

Here is the website: http://www.sofla360.com

I've dabbled with the iOS full-screen code previously, but nothing very complicated nor with a WP theme. Figured I'd start here in case anyone had some insight on this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo. That partially answers my questions, but I'm not sure how best to implement any of those approaches into my WP theme.

Comment: That's **another** problem. Please, try first. Then bring up the problems you face *while coding*

Answer (score 0):

The code I found [here](https://gist.github.com/irae/1042167) works with 99% of my WP-themed website. I created a child theme and placed the code in the head section of the header.php file.